# Can't use <visibilityCondition> in magento2 layout <block>

Tags: magento2

I have a magento2 module that inserts some JS and CSS into the `<head>` of the shop. I want to make the insert conditional, based on another module being active or not. I've researched different ways to do this and found that I should be able to add a `` `<visibilityCondition> `` within my layout file and declare the conditions in a PHP class.

Here is one of the places I found mentioned this. Check under "Custom condition" heading:
https://karnowka.com/posts/magento2-conditional-layout-directives/

I've tried this, but I get the following error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'visibilityCondition': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute, font ).
Line: 749


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'visibilityCondition': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute, font ).
Line: 749

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at 
...
```

I have the following default.xml layout file

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block 
            class="Vendor\Module\Block\InsertSettings" 
            name="Vendor_Module_import.content" 
            template="Vendor_Module::content.phtml"
        >
            <visibilityCondition name="Vendor_Module_import" className="Vendor\Module\Block\CheckProVersionInstalled\Condition" />
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::bundle.css"/>
        <script src="Vendor_Module::bundle.js" />
    </head>
</page>
<!--  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -->
```

And here is the block Conditions.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\CheckProVersionEnabled;

class Condition implements \Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Condition\VisibilityConditionInterface
{

    protected $moduleManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    )
    {
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    }
    
    private static $conditionName = 'pro_version_enabled';

    public function isVisible(array $arguments)
    {
        return $this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Vendor_ModulePro');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::$conditionName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think still there such an xml path like that,

I think you're trying to reach `ifconfig` attribute

See here for detail: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_block

Or the `helper` type

See here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#argument

```
<argument name="helper_method_result" xsi:type="helper" helper="Vendor\CustomModule\Helper\Class::someMethod">
  <param name="firstParam">firstValue</param>
  <param name="secondParam">secondValue</param>
    ...
</argument>
```

Hope this can help